# Better interpolation for Plotly Scatter splines

Tags: python, plotly

Plotly currently supports Catmull-Rom splines for interpolation of the lines between markers on a Scatter plot.

I have graphs where the data is fundamentally a normal distribution. Cubic or Hermite interpolation works very well for this type of data in other graphing frameworks - unfortunately the Catmull-Rom splines (or at least Plotly's implementation of them) really doesn't.

[image]

I've experimented with values of "smoothing" between 0.0 and 1.0 (it seems, though this is not documented, that values over 1.0 make no further difference). Unfortunately, they all look bad.

I've seen a suggestion elsewhere that it might make sense to do my own interpolation using scipy's interpolate.interp2d, and graph that line separately. However, this fails for my use case, since I want the color of the line to be paired with the color of the markers, and for both to appear on the legend as a single item, as shown above.

Has anyone had any experience making the Plotly splines look nicer than they do on a quasi-normal distribution using smoothing=1.0?

Comment: it looks like you can convert matplotlib Figures: https://plot.ly/matplotlib/modifying-a-matplotlib-figure/

Comment: Can you add the code which was used to generate the figure above?